# Unicode to Latin in Teradata Conversion

Tags: unicode, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have been trying to convert Unicode strings to Latin in Teradata version 16.20.32.23. I have seen many online forums but I was not able to formulate a solution. Following are some of the strings that I was unable to convert:

```
hyÃƒÂ¶dyt
lÃƒÂ¶ydÃƒÂ¤t
```

I have tried following solution but function translate_chk does not seems to work.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Translate_Chk ( 'hyÃƒÂ¶dyt' using UNICODE_TO_LATIN) <> 0 
THEN
''
WHEN Translate_Chk ( 'hyÃƒÂ¶dyt' using UNICODE_TO_LATIN ) = 0 
THEN
Translate ( 'hyÃƒÂ¶dyt' using UNICODE_TO_LATIN WITH ERROR)
END AS transalated
```

The error I receive is `SELECT FAILED. 6706: The string contains untranslatable character.`

I think I have reached a dead end, could anyone help me here?

Comment: Works for me in 16.20.31.01. Btw, the 2nd WHE/THENN can be replaced by ELSE

Comment: What could be the reason of this code not working in my environment? Any pointers? Does it have anything to do with the session default characterset?

Comment: Don't know, I assume it would be set to UTF-8 or UTF-16

Comment: Don't see what your default character set would have to do with it. Check for hidden/non-printable characters.  Otherwise, find out which exact piece of your case statement is throwing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Teradata, but the strings you have are double-mis-decoded as `Windows-1252`, which is a variation of `ISO-8859-1` a.k.a `latin1`.  Example to fix in Python:

```
>>> s='hyÃƒÂ¶dyt'
>>> s.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')
'hyödyt'
>>> s='lÃƒÂ¶ydÃƒÂ¤t'
>>> s.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')
'löydät'
```

So not a Teradata solution, but should help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the python code I used, it might help someone. In order to use below code you need to follow below instructions:

Download chilkat package as per your python release:
https://www.chilkatsoft.com/python.asp#winDownloads

Follow installation guidelines in below URL:
https://www.chilkatsoft.com/installWinPython.asp

Open IDLE shell and run the following code

```
import sys
import chilkat

charset = chilkat.CkCharset()

charset.put_FromCharset("utf-8")
charset.put_ToCharset("ANSI")


charset.put_ToCharset("Windows-1252")

success = charset.ConvertFile("source_file_name.csv","target_file_name.csv")
if (success != True):
    print(charset.lastErrorText())
    sys.exit()

print("Success.")
```